# Join user accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

This was never my intention, but I have two accounts on "stackoverflow.com":

1) https://stackoverflow.com/users/370290/j-bruni - my recently registered account

2) https://stackoverflow.com/users/353579/j-bruni - a past, unregistered, account

Check also: http://www.google.com/search?q=Bruni+site%3Astackoverflow.com

---

I would like to know:

1. Is it possible to merge the past unregistered one into the new and properly registered one?
2. Is this the right place to make this request? (If not, where?)

---

Additional info:

What I really want is to **reply a comment** made to my answer at [Portable and safe way to get PATH_INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884041/) - which was submitted using the mentioned **"unregistered account"**. That's why this request is somehow important to me. Right now, I am unable to submit this reply...

Thank you.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste Basically, send an email to team@stackoverflow.com, and they'll walk you through the process to validate your ownership and merge the accounts.

Comment: @Grace Note: That answer was posted before "Flag for moderator attention" was added. Now, I would suggest flagging instead. But either way will work. In this case, I can see that the email addresses are the same, so I'm going to go ahead and merge them.

Comment: @mmyers I always figured that since the team usually has to dictate people to do things like change profile details and such, email was better for the back-and-forth (actually, I might be thinking about account deletion right now). But knowing that flagging is sufficient is good, too.

Comment: @Grace Note: True, if the account details aren't the same, it will require some help from the user. Email is indeed better in that case.

Comment: @Grace Note: Thanks a lot for the information.
@mmyers: Thanks a lot for the merge, and additional information.
Thanks, everybody.