# Why I can't edit my own question?

Tags: support, edits

I have asked a question on this site and now after 2 days it does not allow me to edit my asked question.

So can anyone tell me how I can edit my question or add comments?

Comment: If you don't see an "edit" link under your question, under the keywords and next to the word "link", then you can't edit it.

Comment: Can you link to the original question by chance?

Comment: @Mike: Am curious - under what conditions will one not see the edit link under ones question?

Comment: @JP The only conditions that I can think of are the scenario of being on the wrong account (like here) or if your question was locked by a moderator. That latter one rarely happens, though.

Answer (score 6):

The Stack Overflow account that you used to post *this* question (that is, this question before it was migrated to Meta) has not posted any other questions.

You probably posted the first question before registering and/or have two different accounts that need to be associated with one another. If you can log in to the other account, you can send an email to team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to merge your accounts. You'll have to identify the old user account that is to be merged with the new one and provide some sort of proof that you own both.

Comment: Why do people keep saying to e-mail team@stackoverflow.com? This is the fourth time in ~3 days I've seen that -- just flag for mod attention, mods can merge accounts

Comment: @Michael: It's suggested in tons of posts here on Meta. Not everyone is aware that the recommended course of action has changed. The last time I did this, it was suggested that you do it with an email, and I don't spend much time here on Meta. Maybe we need to update the FAQ to cover this issue.

Comment: @Cody It's not that e-mailing is wrong, it's just kind of unnecessary to get devs involved for something a mod can do

Comment: @Michael Maybe because @Jeff said this himself [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)?

Comment: @Michael In the case of merges, there isn't always a complete match of profile details (see the comment exchange [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58763/join-user-accounts) as an example), so email allows correspondence for confirmation of ownership or any other instructions. So while moderator flagging is an option, email is also necessary at times.

Comment: @marcog I suppose, but information given over two years ago when SO was still in beta probably isn't super reliable

Comment: @Grace If it's the case that usually method A works, but in rare cases people need to resort to method B, you should probably tell them to try method A -- it's like telling somebody whose car broke down that they'll have to buy a new one because sometimes you can't fix them

Comment: @Michael It's labelled faq, should its contents not be kept up-to-date?

Comment: @marcog All posts *should* be kept up to date; that doesn't mean they are. Maybe Jeff does prefer e-mail, but I'm going to keep telling people to mod flag until somebody says otherwise

Comment: @Michael Is it the case that email correspondence is actually the rare need, though? I've seen devs take action on flags that diamonds could easily handle. The rate varies by site, but it doesn't seem to be a huge departure from their normal site habits. Perhaps I'm wrong, but in my eyes, sending the email compared to flagging isn't as drastic a difference as buying a car versus just getting it fixed - it's more like whether I bring it to the dealer who'll give a full tune-up versus bringing it to a local repair shop.

Comment: @marcog As noted by mmyers in the link I provided, that FAQ post was made *before* the ability to flag for moderator attention existed - that's why it's not suggested there.

Comment: @Grace I think so; when would devs ever need to be involved in a user merge? Certainly they *can* do it, and probably do if somebody e-mails them, but that doesn't mean they're actually required; mods should be able to handle it

Comment: @Grace I don't want to sound naggy, but that still doesn't explain why a lone answer in a faq is out-dated. Can someone update it with a more relevant answer? (I don't know enough to answer myself.)

Comment: @Michael I'm not saying they *need* or are *required* for merging - just that they're an entirely appropriate channel to contact for the job that isn't a drastic measure. Mods can certainly handle it and flagging is sufficient.