# What is the reputation required to edit one's own deleted question?

Tags: support, edits, deleted-questions, privileges

One of my friends who is new to the SE recently posted a question on SO and then quickly deleted it after I pointed out some issues.

However, he finds that he cannot edit the question while it is deleted.

What is the required reputation to edit his own question while it is deleted?

Comment: +1 I think (but I'm not sure) either 10 or 100.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This got nothing to do with reputation.

As Oded says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179555/152859):

> With edit, it is now enabled on deleted questions, **unless they are self deletes**, as this can open a window to abuse (self delete, edit and later undelete immediately).

So it means that even with 100000 reputation (and yes, even Jon Skeet) you can't edit a question you deleted yourself. We even get a friendly message saying that as a tooltip over the disabled link:

> [image]

Or in words:

> You cannot edit your own deleted question. Undelete before editing.

In case the question was deleted by others (3 high rep users or one moderator) the OP can always edit it,  even with 1 reputation. This is meant so he can edit, then flag asking to undelete.

Comment: Any reason why this restriction doesn't apply to answers?

Comment: @merlin2011 yes. I don't think it's trivial, so need to look into it, and will probably add to the answer when I know for sure the reason.

Answer (score -2):

I have recently been able to start editing. To confirm what John said (above), I don't have 100 rep. but I can still edit. So the answer would be 10 rep. Here is a link to more information:

[Why I can't edit my own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73754/why-i-cant-edit-my-own-question)

Comment: Were you editing your own *deleted* question? You can edit your own (not-deleted) question without any rep requirement, and the link you mentioned doesn't have anything to do with deleted question.